# localStorage.getItem(...).key is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting this error when I ran my todo app. 
Here is the error,

```
localStorage.getItem(...).key is not a function
```

Here is the code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //var count=localStorage.getItem("todo").length;
    $(".submit").click(function(){
        //count++;      

        localStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify($('.data').val()));


        var i;
        while (localStorage.getItem("todo").key(i)) {
            var value = "<div class='todorow'><div class='todoitem'>"+JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todo").key(i))+"</div><div class='todoremove'>X</div></div>";
            $(".container").append(value);
            console.log(localStorage.getItem("todo").key(i));
            i++;
        }

    });
    $(".container").on("click", ".todoitem", function(){
        jQuery(this).addClass("strike");
    });
    $(".container").on("click", ".todoremove", function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('.todorow').addClass("hide");
    });

    var i;
    while (localStorage.getItem("todo").key(i)) {
            var value = "<div class='todorow'><div class='todoitem'>"+JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todo").key(i))+"</div><div class='todoremove'>X</div></div>";
            $(".container").append(value);
            i++;
    }

});
```

Edit:
I have updated my code. It does not show any error but it doesn't show todo items.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //var count=localStorage.getItem("todo").length;
    $(".submit").click(function(){
        //count++;      

        localStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify($('.data').val()));

        var data;
        data = localStorage.getItem("todo");
        var i;
        while (data[i]) {
            var value = "<div class='todorow'><div class='todoitem'>"+data[i]+"</div><div class='todoremove'>X</div></div>";
            $(".container").append(value);
            console.log(data[i]);
            i++;
        }

    });
    $(".container").on("click", ".todoitem", function(){
        jQuery(this).addClass("strike");
    });
    $(".container").on("click", ".todoremove", function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('.todorow').addClass("hide");
    });
    var data=localStorage.getItem("todo")
    var i;
    while (data[i]) {
            var value = "<div class='todorow'><div class='todoitem'>"+data[i]+"</div><div class='todoremove'>X</div></div>";
            $(".container").append(value);
            i++;
    }

});
```

Edit 2:
I was able to make the page work with below updates,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count=localStorage.length;// get count
    console.log($('.data').val());  // whats in the todo 0
    console.log(localStorage.length); // how much data is in the storage

    var data = new Array();

    var i=0;
        while (i<localStorage.length) {
            data[i]=localStorage.getItem('todo'+i);
            console.log(data[i]);
            i++;
        }
    //var count=localStorage.getItem("todo").length;
    $(".submit").click(function(){
        //count++;      
        data.push($('.data').val());
        localStorage.setItem("todo"+count,$('.data').val());
        count++;
        var i=0;
        $(".todorow").addClass("hide");
        while (i<localStorage.length) {
            var value = "<div class='todorow'><div class='todoitem'>"+data[i]+"</div><div class='todoremove'>X</div></div>";
            $(".container").append(value);
            console.log(data[i]);
            i++;
        }

    });
    $(".container").on("click", ".todoitem", function(){
        jQuery(this).addClass("strike");
    });
    $(".container").on("click", ".todoremove", function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('.todorow').addClass("hide");
    });

    var i=0;
        while (i<localStorage.length) {
            var value = "<div class='todorow'><div class='todoitem'>"+data[i]+"</div><div class='todoremove'>X</div></div>";
            $(".container").append(value);
            console.log(data[i]);
            i++;
        }

});
```

Comment: Yes? `localStorage.getItem(...)` returns a string, strings don't have `.key()`.

Comment: What do you expect `.key(i)` to mean? Your code does not even initialize `i` to any value.

Comment: Also `getItem`  can also return `null`, `null` has no `.key()` either.. :)

Comment: I have updated my code but it doenst work still.

Comment: Is this part:  `localStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify($('.data').val()));`  setting a single item or an array of items?  What is the output of `JSON.stringify($('.data').val())` ?

Answer (score 2):

`localStorage.setItem()` works with strings only.  So when you're calling `localStorage.setItem('todo', somedata)` it is *replacing* the 'todo' value, not adding to it.

Similarly, `localStorage.getItem()` returns strings (or null - so check for that too).

If you want to use localStorage for a list of todos, something like the following may work...

```
// Save your todos array:
var todos = [];  // Empty array if no todos, or you could have todo data already.
localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));


// Load your todos array:
var loadedTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));

var specificTodo = loadedTodos[4];  // Get a specific todo by array index
specificTodo.title = 'abcd';  // Access props
specificTodo.completed = false;  // Access props


// To add a new item to your list of stored todos:
var todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));  // Load the array
todos.push({ title: 'Do some stuff', completed: false });  // Add to the array
localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));  // Save the array
```

Answer (score 0):

if `localStorage.getItem('todo')`  returning an object so if you want to access a property of this object you should parse it first `parse(localStorage.getItem("todo"))`

then if you need to access a property using a variable you have to use `[]` notation instead of `.` notation like

```
var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todo"));
obj[key(i)]
```

and finally if you want to loop through an object you have to use `for of` instead of `while`

Comment: `returning an object ` it never returns an object,.. also I assume you mean `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: I know that  `getItem` method always returning string I mean if it was stringified object like this case . regarding JSON.parse absolutely you are right I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

There were several issues with the code. I was able to make it work with the below tweaks,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count=localStorage.length;// get count
    console.log($('.data').val());  // whats in the todo 0
    console.log(localStorage.length); // how much data is in the storage

    var data = new Array();

    var i=0;
        while (i<localStorage.length) {
            data[i]=localStorage.getItem('todo'+i);
            console.log(data[i]);
            i++;
        }
    //var count=localStorage.getItem("todo").length;
    $(".submit").click(function(){
        //count++;      
        data.push($('.data').val());
        localStorage.setItem("todo"+count,$('.data').val());
        count++;
        var i=0;
        $(".todorow").addClass("hide");
        while (i<localStorage.length) {
            var value = "<div class='todorow'><div class='todoitem'>"+data[i]+"</div><div class='todoremove'>X</div></div>";
            $(".container").append(value);
            console.log(data[i]);
            i++;
        }

    });
    $(".container").on("click", ".todoitem", function(){
        jQuery(this).addClass("strike");
    });
    $(".container").on("click", ".todoremove", function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('.todorow').addClass("hide");
    });

    var i=0;
        while (i<localStorage.length) {
            var value = "<div class='todorow'><div class='todoitem'>"+data[i]+"</div><div class='todoremove'>X</div></div>";
            $(".container").append(value);
            console.log(data[i]);
            i++;
        }

});
```